# PHP and jQuery page refreshing issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem where i am getting data from a PHP script using jQuery which works however the data instantly vanishes as i can only assume the page is refreshing for some reason.

How can i return "Hello world" and keep it on the page?

My HTML/JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var usr = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        $.post("script.php", {username: usr, password: pass}, function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        });
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
First name:

<form id="target">
    <input id="username" type="text" value="User">
    <input id="password" type="text" value="pass">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</div>

<span id="result"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Thanks that works great :D

Comment: @haslam Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form with $( "#target" ).submit() so you need to prevent that from happening with  event.preventDefault();

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

        event.preventDefault(); // add this line

        var usr = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        $.post("script.php", {username: usr, password: pass}, function(result){
            $("#result").html(result);
        });
    });
```